# J2ME (LWUIT) - actionPerformed Not Called

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have two LWUIT `Form`s (Main and Change Password)
One call the other using `actionPerformed` and it works.
Then, in the second one, I need to get some data, processed and return to the first one.
To do that, I'm trying to use `actionPerformed` again. But the Ok button (The Right Button on the Cellphone), NOT calls the `actionPerformed` of the  Change Password `Form`. Just Call the `actionPerformed`  of the Main `Form`. Why?

In other part of the code, I do the same, but with the `MIDlet` and only one `Form` and it works.

There is something to change?
I'm losing a lot of time testing the code, but I can't find the solution

This is the Code of the "Main" `Form`:

```
public class InfoView extends Form implements ActionListener{

    private Command backCommand;
    private Command changePasswordCommand;
    private Command okChangePasswordForm;

     private ChangePassword changePasswordForm;

    public InfoView(Command backC){

        super();

        this.addCommand(backC);
        this.setBackCommand(backC);

        this.setScrollableY(true);

        this.setTitle(LanguageManager.getText("RootTitle"));

        changePasswordCommand = new Command(LanguageManager.getText("ChangePassword"), Constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND);

        okChangePasswordForm = new Command(LanguageManager.getText("Ok"), Constants.OK_CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND);

        this.addAllCommands();       

        this.initForm();
    }

    public void initForm(){

        Style s = this.getStyle();

        s.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
        s.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        this.addCommandListener(this);

        backCommand = new Command(LanguageManager.getText("Back"), Constants.BACK_COMMAND);

    }

    private void addAllCommands(){

        this.addCommand(changePasswordCommand);

        this.addCommand(changeContactInfoCommand);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        //Obtengo la Opción seleccionada
        Command cmd = arg0.getCommand();

        if (cmd == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(cmd.getId()));

        switch (cmd.getId()) {

            case Constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND:

                System.out.println("CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND");

                //this.setGlassPane(null);

                if (changePasswordForm == null) {
                    changePasswordForm = new ChangePassword();
                    changePasswordForm.addCommand(backCommand);
                    changePasswordForm.addCommand(okChangePasswordForm);
                    changePasswordForm.addCommandListener(this);
                    changePasswordForm.setBackCommand(backCommand);
                }

                changePasswordForm.show();
                arg0.consume();
                break;

            case Constants.BACK_COMMAND:

                System.out.println("BACK_COMMAND");

                //20111004 MB: Cuando vuelvo, desincronizo para que al 
                //cambiar de tarjeta funcione
                //protocolManager.deSync();

                addAllCommands();

                this.show();

                this.editInfoForm = null;
                this.changePasswordForm = null;

                System.gc();

                break; 

            case Constants.OK_CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND:

                System.out.println("OK_CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND");

                this.editInfoForm = null;

                this.show();

                System.gc();

                break;                
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Code of the Change Password `Form`:

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout;
import Project.language.LanguageManager;

public class ChangePassword extends Form implements ActionListener {

    private TextField oldPassword;
    private TextField newPassword;
    private TextField repeatNewPassword;

    public ChangePassword(){

        super ();

        this.setTitle(LanguageManager.getText("ChangePasswordTitle"));

        addCommandListener(this);

        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        this.addComponent(new Label(LanguageManager.getText("Actual")));

        oldPassword = new TextField("");
        oldPassword.setConstraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);

        this.addComponent(oldPassword);

        this.addComponent(new Label(LanguageManager.getText("New")));

        newPassword = new TextField("");
        newPassword.setConstraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);

        this.addComponent(newPassword);

        this.addComponent(new Label(LanguageManager.getText("Repeat")));

        repeatNewPassword = new TextField("");
        repeatNewPassword.setConstraint(TextArea.PASSWORD);

        this.addComponent(repeatNewPassword);
    }

    private String getOldPass(){
        return this.oldPassword.getText();
    }

    private String getNewPass(){
        return this.newPassword.getText();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        Command cmd = arg0.getCommand();

        String oldPasswordVar = getOldPass();
        String newPasswordVar = getNewPass();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Got It!**

In the `InfoView.actionPerformed(...)`, under switch `Constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND:` in the `ChangePassword()` constructor the **`ChangePassword.addCommandListener(...)` is over-written by `changePasswordForm.addCommandListener(this);`** Hence when the `ChangePassword` form is being displayed the keyEvents of `InfoView.actionPerformed(...)` are active.

**Code Snippet #1**

```
...
case Constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMMAND:
    changePasswordForm = new ChangePassword();
    changePasswordForm.addCommand(backCommand);
    changePasswordForm.addCommandListener(this); //<-- PROBLEM, because 'this' 
                                                 //          is referring to
                                                 //          'InfoView' and NOT
                                                 //          'ChangePassword'
    changePasswordForm.setBackCommand(backCommand);
...
```

**Code Snippet #2**

```
public ChangePassword(){
 ...
 addCommandListener(this);   //<-- Being over-written
 ...
}
```

**The solution** is to just comment or remove the **PROBLEM** statement marked in code snippet #1 above.

I would also recommend to create `backCommand` inside the class `ChangePassword`, so that it doesn't get hidden by `InfoView.backCommand`.